# ffmpeg to cut beginning and fade in audio

Tags: ffmpeg

I've got a bunch of spoken word mp3 files, which all have the same intro talking and music, and then the real content begins. So it goes roughly like this:

```
00:00 Standard intro spoken word
00:20 Standard intro music
00:35 The content
```

The timings are not always the same (can vary by 5 secs). So I'd to cut the first 25 seconds and then fade in the next five seconds. And then output the file in the same mp3 format. Is this possible with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This command should work for you:

```
ffmpeg -ss 25 -i input.mp3 -af "afade=type=in:start_time=0:duration=5" -c:a libmp3lame output.mp3
```

`-ss 25` will start the input after the first 25 seconds.

`afade` filter will fade in the audio from the specified start time for the next 5 seconds.

Comment: When using `ffplay` the `start_time` must be same as `-ss`. **E.G.** `ffplay "03 Lorelei.m4a" -ss 25 -af "afade=type=in:start_time=25:duration=5"`

Comment: @Camille Goudeseune I've just tested your edit and the output is wrong - the sound starts at 25th second with 25 seconds of silence...

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I've tested this command with `ffplay` and the parameters seem to work differently here indeed - thanks for the note. But I'm not sure if it should be added to the answer as `ffplay` is normally used just for temporary play, not to do the cut the question asked.